# Adobe Flex Image control source set to https program call fails (SecurityError: Error #2122)

Tags: image, apache-flex, https

The following flex codes set image control source as 'a https program call' to get a image file and clone image data into a bitmap, then add it as child to another image viewer:

```
    <ns1:ImageViewer id="imageViewer" bitmapScaleFactorMax="5" bitmapScaleFactorMin=".05"width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" />
    <mx:Image id="navImage" source="{_imageURL}" complete="{loadOK()}" />

    private function loadOK():void
    {
        Alert.show("load ok");
      try {
        preImageData = (navImage.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.clone();
        Alert.show("clone ok");
      } catch (err:Error) {
        Alert.show"error="+err);
      }
        preImage = new Bitmap(preImageData);
        Alert.show("bitmap ok");
        preImage.scaleX /= scaleRatio;
        preImage.scaleY /= scaleRatio;
        imageViewer.addChildAt(preImage, 0);
        Alert.show("cloned navImage add to imageBiewer ok");
        // some further codes
     }
     public function appStart():void
     {
        _imageURL = "https://fs.mysite.com/getimgurl.jsp?pic=logo";
     }
```

'https://fs.mysite.com/getimgurl.jsp?pic=logo' actually returns a string 'https://fs.mysite.com/img/mylogo.jpg'.

I've set policy in crossdomain.xml on ap.mysite.com:

```
<allow-access-from domain="ap.mysite.com" secure="false" />
```

On ap.mysite.com, I write a jsp to include this swf and run it on browser, it only displays "load ok" but never "clone ok" and the exception shows

> error=SecurityError: Error #2122

If I directly se

```
_imageURL = https://fs.mysite.com/img/mylogo.jpg
```

then "clone ok" will be displayed.

I thought the problem is that image control source doesn't accept program call but when I change https to http of that program call string, it works well.

Some people tell me about "loadPolicyFile" and "allowDomain" but I don't know them. What do I do wrong or what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following code and it will work

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("yoursite/crossdomain.xml");
```

Comment: You have used crossdomain.xml in your site. But flex does not know where to find the policy file so that it can read it to determine whether to permit applications to load data from servers other than their own . So we have to instruct them to load the policy file using `loadPolicyFile`